# 16 Thread / 16 core code profiling with Java / Eclipse TPTP on Linux system

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse, profiling, multicore

I have developed a nice multi-Threaded genetic algorithm in Java that runs on a 16-core system running CentOS with 128GB of RAM.

I want to use a code profiler to see if I can figure out which portion of the code is getting bogged down when I increase the number of mutations in my simulation beyond a certain point.  Memory doesn't seem to be the issue.

So I installed VNC and Eclipse 3.6SR2 on the server and installed the TPTP plugin.

PROBLEM: The biggest issue is that it doesn't look like eclipse is using more than one core when I am doing the TPTP "execution time analysis" (I checked using 'top').  Normally when the program is run from the command line it uses as many cores as there are threads in the program.

Is there a way to fix this in the eclipse configuration?

Comment: I just checked and when using "Debug" or "Run" all 16 cores are used but when using "Profile" only one core is being used.  Another problem is memory, under my Debug/Run configurations. I allocate 32GB to the JVM with the -Xmx32g option, however TPTP doesn't seem to be allocating the memory ... or the processors.

Answer (score 0):

Get a real profiler like [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com) and add the agent to your application at startup.

Then you can open an SSH tunnel with the port where the agent is running and you can remotely profile your application. It has a quite good documentation and a healthy community in their forums. And in my opinion YourKit is great for multithreaded applications, I use it a lot.

No need for VNC and installing Eclipse on a production server.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

A profiler that uses JVMTI should not change the multi-core thread distribution with respect to a regular execution. TPTP may not be the best option for you.

There are several powerful Java profilers in the market. The most well-known free option is [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) and a commmercial alternative with much more powerful analytic capabilities in the area of multi-threading and monitor contention analysis is [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) - there's a fully functional free trial.